# How to print out tab content from msqli fetch array specific number of times?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, fetch

So what am I trying to do is print tab content from a `mysqli_fetch_array` three times in one column, then move into a second column, and then the third column.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

    <!-- First column -->

    <div class="d-flex flex-column">

        <?php echo $tab_content; ?>

    </div>

    <!-- Second column -->

    <div class="d-flex flex-column">

    </div>

    <!-- Third column -->

    <div class="d-flex flex-column">

    </div>
</div>
```

and the php

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$tab_content .= '
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">

<img class="card-img-top" src="">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">'.$row['job_name'].'</h4>
<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">'.$row['price'].'</h6>
<p class="card-text">'.$row['job_desc'].'</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
';
}
```

This is what am I trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following(In your PHP file):

```
$i=1;
$tabs = [];
$tab_content = null;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$tab_content .= '
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">

<img class="card-img-top" src="">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">'.$row['job_name'].'</h4>
<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">'.$row['price'].'</h6>
<p class="card-text">'.$row['job_desc'].'</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
';
if($i % 3 === 0)
{
    $tabs[] = $tab_content;
    $tab_content = null;
}
$i++;
}

$tab_content = '<div class="d-flex flex-column">' . implode('</div><div class="d-flex flex-column">', $tabs) . '</div>';
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <?php echo $tab_content; ?>
</div>
```

This will store posts for each column in array as values, and then it uses `implode()` to convert them to html string, while concatenating the html tags in it. And adds prefix and postfix `div` tag.

Comment: Your if(mod) is filtering out some of his tabs (keeping only every 3rd), and if he had 9 tabs, would result in unwanted results?

Comment: @Randall No, it is not keeping every 3rd but instead it is adding every 3 into columns.

Comment: Ah ha! so you are right. Brain was not seeing the initial .=

Comment: @mega6382 This is working, and thanks, but can you help me with one more thing, please. How do I putt gutter between cards so I have nice space in between

Comment: @Mayketi I don't understand please explain a bit, do you mean formated html or some margin between the elements?

Comment: @mega6382 yea I mean margins between elements. Like on the picture I posted

Comment: @Mayketi You, can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) for this, I cannot provide much information like this, but you can look into some tutorials for better understanding, like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/).

Comment: @Mayketi And be sure to accept this answer as helpful if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Php Code Like This, Where While Loop on Only First Div and then its display dynamic:**

**Working Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4msw-ep80**

### Note: i m Using Array For Data Display in while loop.

```
<?php

$a = array(
  array(
    'job' => 'job 1',
    'price' => '500',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),
  array(
    'job' => 'job 2',
    'price' => '1000',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),
  array(
    'job' => 'job 3',
    'price' => '2000',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),

  array(
    'job' => 'job 4',
    'price' => '500',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),
  array(
    'job' => 'job 5',
    'price' => '1000',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),
  array(
    'job' => 'job 6',
    'price' => '2000',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),
  array(
    'job' => 'job 7',
    'price' => '500',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),
  array(
    'job' => 'job 8',
    'price' => '1000',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  ),
  array(
    'job' => 'job 9',
    'price' => '2000',
    'job_desc' => 'Bla Bla Bla',
  )

);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:50px;">

<div class="container">        
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">

<?php
foreach($a as $value) {
?>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-danger"><span class="label label-danger pull-right"><?php echo $value['price']; ?></span> <?php echo $value['job']; ?> 
          <br><br>
          <span> <p> <?php echo $value['job_desc']; ?></p></span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"> Connect </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>

<?php
}
?>


    </div><!--/row-->    
  </div><!--/col-12-->
</div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Output Like This:**

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:50px;">

<div class="container">        
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-danger"><span class="label label-danger pull-right"> 250kn </span> Job Name 1  
          <br><br>
          <span> <p> Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla  Bla Bla</p></span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"> Connect </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right"> 250kn </span> Job Name 2
          <br><br>
          <span> <p> Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla  Bla Bla</p></span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"> Connect </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-primary"><span class="label label-primary pull-right"> 250kn </span> Job Name 3
          <br><br>
          <span> <p> Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla  Bla Bla</p></span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"> Connect </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      <!-- Start Row 2 -->
      
       <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-danger"><span class="label label-danger pull-right"> 250kn </span> Job Name 4  
          <br><br>
          <span> <p> Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla  Bla Bla</p></span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"> Connect </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right"> 250kn </span> Job Name 5
          <br><br>
          <span> <p> Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla  Bla Bla</p></span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"> Connect </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-primary"><span class="label label-primary pull-right"> 250kn </span> Job Name 6
          <br><br>
          <span> <p> Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla  Bla Bla</p></span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"> Connect </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      <!-- End Row 2 -->
      
    </div><!--/row-->    
  </div><!--/col-12-->
</div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
```